# Test project call to instantiate Window hangs when using BackgroundWorker

Tags: wpf, testing, automated-tests, backgroundworker

I am trying to set up a test suite for a recently-written WPF/C# app.  I did not use any sort of MVVM pattern, which I realize makes automated testing much more difficult, but this is the current state of things and my boss is not going to give me extra time for a rewrite.  So I am trying to make the best of the situation.

In my test project, I am calling the `MainWindow()` ctor.  I kick off the `DoWork` method of a `BackgroundWorker` right before its creation, to be able to send keypresses via an `(Action)delegate` through the window's `Dispatcher`.  However, when I call `bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` before calling the `MainWindow` ctor, the ctor does not get executed (I put breakpoints in it and nada).  If I remove the call to `RunWorkerAsync` then the ctor works correctly. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the implementation of BackgroundWorker .

IsVMBusy = true;

var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>

```
   {

       //Do task here

    };
```

worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>

```
        {
            IsVMBusy = false;
        };
        IsVMBusy = true;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: I understand how `BackgroundWorker` works. What is the issue here is why calling the `DoWork` method in this situation makes a difference.